# Free shipping text on Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I am using this code to display free shipping when product price is >= freeshipping value (49€). But product price looks to be working only, for example, when it's between 50 and 99€. When it goes to like 109€ and 129€, the code does not work anymore and the shipping text is not shown. It looks like the comparison between values is only done between a limited number or characters. Any clue how to fix this?

```
 {assign var='freeshipping' value=Configuration::get('PS_SHIPPING_FREE_PRICE')}
              {if $product.price >= $freeshipping}
              <div class="freeshipping-message" ><b>FREE SHIPPING</b></div>
              {/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$product.price_amount` instead of `$product.price` because `$product.price` returns the formatted price with the currency sign.

So in your code, you are actually comparing a string and an integer like that:

```
if "25,00 €" >= 49
```